# Deactivating a pipeline in devops center

Tags: sandbox, release, devopscenter

Good morning dear, long time no ask. I'm testing Devops Center and I'm curious to know if you can disable the pipeline in Devops Center.

Any help or information is welcome.
Greetings!

[image]

Comment: You can not deactivate if any change is in progress.  Check here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.devops_center_pipeline_activate.htm&type=5 and https://elements.cloud/app/uploads/2022/07/Getting-started-with-Salesforce-DevOps-Center-and-Elements.cloud-1.2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to deactivate a pipeline if a change is in progress.

As per [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.devops_center_pipeline_activate.htm&type=5):

> - You and your team can create work items after a pipeline is activated.
> - You can’t inactivate a pipeline after changes have been promoted through it.
> - You can edit only inactive pipelines. If you haven’t yet promoted changes, you can deactivate it, make the changes, and then reactivate it.
> - You can remove pipeline environments only if the pipeline is inactive.